# How publish and use the npm packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish

#### My module

`npmpublicrepo
   -- package.json
   -- test.js`

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "npmpublicrepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

test.js

```
exports.testMessage = function() {
   console.log("test");  
};
```

> npm publish

This got successfully published and I can see the page in npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmpublicrepo

#### My normal project to use above package

`npmpublicrepousage
   -- package.json
   -- index.js`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "npmpublicrepousage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "npmpublicrepo": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

after doing `npm install`, I can see the folder in `./node_modules/npmpublicrepo` and I am able to see the module's code properly.

#### Running a script which use the module

Then, I use the previous module in the script `./index.js` :

```
var test = require("npmpublicrepo");
test.testMessage();
```

But, running the script fails :

> node ./index.js

...with the error :

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmpublicrepo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vimalprakash/Documents/Projects/NodeJs/npmpublicrepousage/index.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

I don't know what i am missing.

My node version : v7.4.0

My NPM version : 4.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your npmpublicrepo package.json you expose a wrong [primary entry point to your program](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main). You set a file that does not exist:

```
"main": "index.js"
```

You could rename test.js to index.js or you could expose the test.js file as the primary entry point to your program with:

```
"main": "test.js"
```